# While submitting APNS: TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char[]' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str

Tags: python, openssl, apple-push-notifications

While submitting an APNS notification I get the following error - that happens after manually setting the key without the b as of another question of mine. The code is:

```
token = jwt.encode(
{
    'iss': TEAM_ID,
    'iat': time.time()
},
secret,
algorithm= ALGORITHM,
headers={
    'alg': ALGORITHM,
    'kid': APNS_KEY_ID,
})
```

while the code triggering the exception is:

```
def _bytes_to_bio(self, data):
    """
    Return a _MemoryBIO namedtuple of (BIO, char*).

    The char* is the storage for the BIO and it must stay alive until the
    BIO is finished with.
    """
    data_char_p = self._ffi.new("char[]", data) #here is the exception
    bio = self._lib.BIO_new_mem_buf(
        data_char_p, len(data)
    )
    self.openssl_assert(bio != self._ffi.NULL)

    return _MemoryBIO(self._ffi.gc(bio, self._lib.BIO_free), data_char_p)
```

and the error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line
>   57, in encode
>       json_payload, key, algorithm, headers, json_encoder   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 98, in
>   encode
>       key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 226,
>   in prepare_key
>       key = load_pem_public_key(key, backend=default_backend())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py",
>   line 24, in load_pem_public_key
>       return backend.load_pem_public_key(data)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py",
>   line 314, in load_pem_public_key
>       return b.load_pem_public_key(data)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py",
>   line 1088, in load_pem_public_key
>       mem_bio = self._bytes_to_bio(data)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py",
>   line 490, in _bytes_to_bio
>       data_char_p = self._ffi.new("char[]", data) 
>   TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char[]' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str